# Credit card chargeback for a travel booking site?

Tags: travel

I booked a hotel on Booking.com but the room was not as described on the website.  It's for Caesar's Palace in Las Vegas.  The resort has different towers with different names and the booking references a specific tower (Roman Tower).  Booking.com references a wet/dry minibar, bathrobes, flat screen TV, in-room safe, but none of those things were in my room.  It also shows a picture of the bathroom which is for a suite.  I know this because for my second night I had the hotel change me to a different room.  Booking.com also advertises a $25 resort fee when it's actually $28.

I sent Booking.com an email and they said they are not responsible for information about hotels because they get the information from the hotel itself.  That seems a bit fishy to me since it gives them the right to be wrong in every instance.  Caesar's is saying the same thing....it's a Booking.com problem and they can't be responsible for what they put on their site.  I went to the Caesar's site and their information about the room is accurate.

I wanted to know if anyone else had a similar incident and what the result was.  I don't like doing chargebacks unless it's a last resort.  I also only want a refund for the 1st night only since the hotel moved me to a different room on the second night.  I can understand that there are sometimes small discrepancies with room descriptions but the reservation used the specific tower name and none of the rooms have the features they are describing.  It's like being in a different hotel altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is? "Has this happened to anyone else" is off-topic. Is there something you would like asked?

Comment: I am very sorry to learn about your experience with the Caesars Palace. I would like to investigate this matter, could you please provide me your booking number? Thanks, Tal
Booking.com Team

Comment: Tal, do you have any way for me to get you the information privately?

Comment: you can send me the relevant information to: customer.web@booking.com ; please mention your post on stackexchange. Thanks, Tal. Booking.com Team

Comment: Thanks but I'm already working with someone from Booking.com.

Comment: Tal, the customer representative was just a waste of time.  They said I did not notify the hotel so there's nothing they can do, but that was false.  I gave them the specific time and date I contacted the hotel and all I got was another apology and said the matter was closed.  They offered to review the complaint again if I wanted and I chose that option and I simply got another apology and was told that the matter was closed.  I went ahead and wrote a review for the site and urged customers to go to other sites for more accurate information.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely dispute only partial charge with the credit card company (for the first day and the difference of the resort fee). You can provide the answers you got from the site and from the hotel blaming each other, and have your credit card company force them to figure it out. They pay penalty on charge-backs, not you.

You might find that the "fine print" says that the information is for reference only and you may get a different room in a different building, etc etc. However, I believe if what you describe is true, your charge-back will be justified.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It's because of the fact that a specific tower was mentioned that leads me to believe there was some misrepresentation going on.